# Why does this simple integer division in Python 3 give me one less than expected answer?

Tags: python

Python 3. I have this command ->

```
int(29930125722068957199361/65537)
```

I get 456690506463050752, but answer should be 456690506463050753

Oh and this happens only in Python 3+ , not when executing direct in Python prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of floating point error. Floating point numbers have a limited size in memory and can only be so accurate for some values.

Instead, use the `//` (floor division) operator for an accurate result:

```
print(29930125722068957199361 // 65537)
# 456690506463050753
```

Comment: But the numbers being divided are integers. And since this is a case of being exactly divisible, where is the floating point aspect coming from? Other than that division is always a fp result in Python 3+. And if that was it, still my cast to int or a math.floor should bring it back to the proper int value right?

Comment: @Stubborn You are right, division results are always floating point. For example, `type(1 / 1)` is `float`. Anyway, when the floating point aspect comes in, you are already losing precision that cannot be "regained" through conversion to `int` or `math.floor`.